# Tablet Apps for Simple Processing of RAW files

Tags: software, raw, image-processing, android, tablet

What tablet Apps would you recommend for simple RAW processiong on a tablet?
Currently using Samsung Tab 2, 7 inch tablet.

My main concern is just open the RAW file and do some Cropping and upload onto Facebook when traveling overseas.

Comment: It would be awesome if Canon would release a simple DPP app for simple tweaks, as that's as far as most of my photo processing goes

Comment: Photoshop Express may do the trick... I can't say for Android (iPad seems to have better options) so I didn't post as an answer. At any rate, you may find it slow if you do a lot of editing.

Answer (score 3):

I looked into this with the iPad and found it very impractical for any workflow to use RAW. The transfer rate is horribly slow and it sucks down battery life at a nasty rate.

Your best bet would be to shoot RAW/JPEG and import only JPEG to significantly cut down on transfer time and significantly open up your options to which app you would use. If you think about this workflow, you have no need to import RAW into the iPad when you aren't doing any heavy lifting in post anyways. As for apps, while it may not sound professional, the new iPhoto app would meet your needs with a JPEG workflow nicely.

Comment: Agreed. As awesome as tablets are and as much power as they have (compared to computers of just a few years ago), they are just completely inadequate for RAW processing.

Comment: It's much better on the iPad 3. I've used both iPhoto and Snapseed with Pentax K-5 raw images and it's surprisingly snappy. It's also not messing around with the embedded thumbnail, it's producing a fullsized JPEG as the outcome.

Comment: He also mentioned that he's using a Samsung tablet... Assuredly not running IOS...

Comment: Looks like I swung and missed with the OS. The practicality issue is still present with the usage of RAW on tablet. File size and level of manipulation doesn't add up.

Comment: Snapseed for Android should be out soon. That doesn't help right now, of course, but it's something to look forward to.